# Visual Studio build which employs nuget fails trying to connect to proget:81 and artifact:8081 endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

at work I have to build some rather outdated visual studio c-sharp project. Disclaimer: I am a visual studio and windows noob. When I launch provided batch script which wraps around `msbuild.exe` then quite early in the process the build fails. The reason is because `nuget` tries to connect to two endpoints, http://proget:81 and http://artifact:8081, and fails doing so.

`NuGet.config` file which is part of the repository includes entries which contain references to those two endpoints.

I would imagine that these two endpoints would be enabled by some local service programs I am not aware of. I tried to google for them but alas little is available on this that would relate to my problem. What is puzzling, according to some second hand knowledge, this c-sharp project is expected to build without installing anything that is outside of standard visual studio installer packages. Thus, I would assume that this would be a matter that maybe my visual studio installation is missing some components I am not aware of?

I tried to remove those offending entries from `NuGet.config`, but then the build fails because it is missing `log4net 2.0.3` and `Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3`.

Comment: The site seems to be like api url and be deprecated. Do you try to manually re-add missing packages into the project?

Comment: Yes, I did try to manually add missing packages and this led me to discover that the problem was caused not by those two endpoints but by nuget being unable to establish SSL/TLS connection (which by itself is also puzzling because another build I was working with on the same machine was using nuget without such problems).

Comment: Did you have a try to access this URL through browser on your local environment?